# Git pull needs to discard local files

Tags: git

I have a git setup with a shared repository. As I'm working on 2 PC's I push my personal branches.

I'm rebasing frequently with the develop branch so I need to force a push (git push -f origin feature). But when I want to pull a feature branch whith the forced changes I always get merge conflicts.

Is it possible to force a pull and overwrite the local files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're wanting to just get to the state that you were at on the other machine when you force pushed, just `reset --hard` to the head that you want:

```
$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard origin/<yourbranch>
```